# How to force the user to enter function parameters as a Unicode string?

Tags: c++, utf-8, parameters

For example, I have a function/method which takes a string parameter of type `const char*` as follow:

```
void func(const char* str){
    // ..........
}

// When using, the user has two options:
func("Hello 日本語 سلام Ä भारतीय ไทย");    // option 1, non-UTF-8
func(u8"Hello 日本語 سلام Ä भारतीय ไทย");  // option 2, UTF-8
```

**How to force the user to enter the function parameter as a Unicode string like "option 2" instead of any other encoding like "option 1".**

Comment: The second option won't compile in C++20 because the string type now uses `char8_t`.

Comment: @chris so in C++20 the answer is obvious then, but for C++11 there seem to be no way to enforce it.

Comment: @Slava Technically, `char8_t` doesn't enforce UTF-8 any more than `char` does. But it does document what the function expects without a comment.

Comment: Unless you wrap the `char`/`char8_t` data in a class that enforces UTF-8, you could simply use `const wchar_t*` (UTF-16 on Windows, UTF-32 on other platforms) or `const char16_t*` (UTF-16 on all platforms) instead for Unicode strings. Otherwise, if you are going to use `const char*`/`const char8_t*` then you will just have to make the function validate the data really is UTF-8 before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `const char* str`, there is no way to enforce at compile time that it points to a string with particular encoding. At run time it is possible to inspect whether the string contains invalid unicode sequences, but lack of such invalid sequences is not a guarantee that the string is necessarily unicode.

Until C++11, there is no difference between the types of "string" and u8"string" (except potentially difference in the length of the array). and both can be passed into a function accepting `const char*`.

Since C++20, u8"string" is an array of `char8_t`. Such literal cannot be passed into a function accepting `const char*`. If you change the function to accept `const char8_t*`, then it wouldn't accept a literal `"string"`. Note that this doesn't technically guarantee that the function is passed strings in correct encoding, but at least it will be more difficult to do that by accident.

Comment: Even if it is in the correct encoding, will it be in the expected normalization?  So many rules.